# Is it possible to design Fill in the blanks type format in linear layout in Android?

Tags: android

how can you design a linear layout in android,when you have a format like fill in the blanks?

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="168dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="@string/blank1first"
    android:id="@+id/blank1part"
    />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="68dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/blank1"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="dsasda" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="86dp"
    android:text="@string/blank2first"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

Comment: Can you explain what a "format like feel in the blanks" ? Maybe share a link to an example

Comment: illustration is best way to explain your issue.

Comment: @NicolásCarrasco a common format which are used in paper..

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing `layout_weight` attribute:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="@string/blank1first"
    android:id="@+id/blank1part"
    />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/blank1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="dsasda" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="86dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/blank2first"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="@string/blank1first"
        android:id="@+id/blank1part"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/blank1"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="dsasda" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/blank2first"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
```